# How to perform a spatial query using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have two shapefiles: Italian postcodes; and Italian municipalities. Both are polygon format and both contains the name of each relevant shape. I'd like to add to the postcode shapefile a field for the postcode's municipality. I believe this is a spatial query. How do I do this using GeoPandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a spatial query can be done with the spatial join function [`sjoin`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html) of GeoPandas. It will look something like:

```
res = geopandas.sjoin(postcodes, municipalities, op='contains')
```

where the `op` will depend on the specific spatial relationship of your data.

See https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins for more.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for